# why $\log(n!)$ isn't zero?

Tags: logarithms

I have wondered that why the  $\log (n!)$ isn't zero for $n \in N$.

Because I think that $\log (1)$ is zero so all following numbers after multiplying the result will become zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by (lgn)!?

Comment: to format mathematics insert the text code between dollar signs: If you meant to write $\log(n)!$ then you type \log(n)! between dollar signs. Try it!

Comment: Do you mean $\lg(n!)$? That’s $\lg 1+\lg 2+\ldots+\lg n$: you’re **adding** the logs, not multiplying them.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the stupid question. I got it and you can answer it so that I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean $\log (n!)$ with the exclamation mark inside the parentheses, which was Brian's suggestion.

Comment: You’re welcome; I’ve turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might as well make an answer of it.

$$\begin{align*}
\lg(n!)&=\lg(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n)\\
&=\lg 1+\lg 2+\lg 3+\ldots+\lg n\\
&=\lg 2+\lg 3+\ldots+\lg n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so it won’t be $0$ unless $n=1$ (or $n=0$): you’re adding the logs, not multiplying them.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it.